# Python: multiple installations, How to fix on one python version?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am running python on `Macbook Air` and I realized that I have many versions of python installed available via multiple paths

```
hhimanshu@air~ - 11:43:51  $ which python
python is /Users/hhimanshu/.virtualenvs/envs/bi/bin/python
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
python is /opt/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python

(bi)hhimanshu@air~ - 11:56:54  $ /Users/hhimanshu/.virtualenvs/envs/bi/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.2

(bi)hhimanshu@air~ - 11:57:03  $ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.3 -- EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)

(bi)hhimanshu@air~ - 11:57:13  $ /opt/local/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.3

(bi)hhimanshu@air~ - 11:57:22  $ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

My `$PATH` value looks like

```
(bi)hhimanshu@air~ - 11:57:28  $ echo $PATH
/Users/hhimanshu/.virtualenvs/envs/bi/bin:/Users/hhimanshu/.pythonbrew/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/bin:/Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/bin:/Users/hhimanshu/.rbenv/shims:/Users/hhimanshu/.rbenv/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/hhimanshu/.ec2/bin
```

I see issue because when I use `virtualenv` and see what python version I have, I see

```
 $ yolk -l
    Python          - 2.7.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
    pip             - 1.2.1        - active 
    setuptools      - 0.6c11       - active 
    wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7)
    yolk            - 0.4.3        - active
```

But what I need is

```
$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.3 -- EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)
```

How can I fix my environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following command will help you.

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:$PATH
```

and check whether path is updated or not.

Or you can edit the respective configuration (.profile in home directory) file for permanent change in Mac OS. (In Unix system there is a file named .bash_profile which should be edited)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have put your virtual environment in your `PATH`, so the first Python that is encountered is used - which is 2.7.2.

You should never put the venv in your path; that will cause other problems later on as well. To activate a virtual environment, `source /path/to/virtulaenv/bin/activate`, then later, type `deactivate` to reset your shell.

Remove the first two components in your `PATH`:

`/Users/hhimanshu/.virtualenvs/envs/bi/bin:/Users/hhimanshu/.pythonbrew/bin:`

(the virtualenvrionment and pythonbrew) by modifying your dotfiles; close and restart your Terminal for the PATH changes to take effect.